# Set the Modulation Wheel Value programmatically

Tags: javascript, midi

I'm musician and using a music software which provides a plugin in which I can use some javascript code to edit or create MIDI Data in Real Time. I want to implement a logic that increases the value of the Modulation Wheel when a specific button or note on the Keyboard is pressed. My problem is that I have no skills in Javascript programming and I don't know how to start. Can somebody help me with some tipps that will push me in the right direction?

```
function HandleMIDI(event) {

//How to check if the key which was pressed is a specific note like "A2" ?
//How to check if the key which was pressed is a specific button on the Keyboard ?
if (event instanceof Note) {

//How to overwrite the current value of the Mod Wheel ?

event.send();
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: You should at least tell the name of the framework you are using. Without knowing that, how is anyone supposed to know the code?

Comment: As I sayed I'm using a music software called "Mainstage" and the plugin which allow javascript code is called "Scripter". It uses the JavaScriptCore framework.

Comment: And by affecting the modulation wheel you are trying to affect the note’s pitch?

Comment: No. I'm doing many other stuff like changing volume of some instruments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and trying, I found this solution

```
function HandleMIDI(event)
{
    if(event instanceof NoteOn && event.pitch == 84)
    {
        var modWheel = new ControlChange();
        modWheel.channel=5;
        modWheel.number=1;
        modWheel.value=20;
        modWheel.send();
        modWheel.trace();
    }
    else
    {
        event.send();
    }
}
```